# set mouse position on rooted android device

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, mouse, root

Kind of related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502876/set-mouse-position-in-software).

On a rooted Android phone, how do I set the position of the mouse from within an app. (The mouse is a bluetooth mouse.)

The other question mentioned it's possible with root or ADB, but not how.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this library to inject events: https://github.com/radhoo/android-event-injector

And add mouse move event method in `Events.java`, below is a example to send a relative mouse move event:

```
    public int sendMouseMove(int deltaX, int deltaY) {
        intSendEvent(m_nId, EV_REL, REL_X, deltaX);
        intSendEvent(m_nId, 0, 0, 0);
        intSendEvent(m_nId, EV_REL, REL_Y, deltaY);
        intSendEvent(m_nId, 0, 0, 0);
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: It's odd to receive answers a year after asking, I'll mark one as answer soon.

Comment: @zproxy no, write permission of `/dev/input/event` is needed.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround, until android gets fixed, might be to have the app connect to localhost as adb client and issue adb commands.

On the adb shell you can open /dev/input/uevent device to write mouse events include, absolute position

[Set mouse position in software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20502876/set-mouse-position-in-software)